IPBan nlog.config 'archiveEvery' parameter
I have been using IPBan for a few days,
and now there are many log files,
with each file only containing a few lines of log.
I'd want to configure the nlog.config file to change the archive period.
I've found an archiveEvery parameter,
but when I change it from Day to Week,
it doesn't archive every week, instead, it just stops archiving.
Any help would be appreciated...
I've searched IPBan config docs, but it seems there is no single article about this config.
Even in the nlog-project/NLog.xsd,
there is no single statement on how to change it but only says
Indicates whether to automatically archive log files every time the specified time passes. I've never dealt with nlog
so I have no idea what to do...

Maybe you can post the entire contents of NLog.config that you are modifying? Notice when troubleshooting NLog then it is recommended to use throwConfigExceptions="true" and also look in the NLog InternalLogger for clues. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting
